# Strings before \r not displayed

Tags: python

I have this little problem in Python when using

```
print ",".join(array)
```

For example, when using `array=['dog\r', 'monkey', 'pig']` the output looks like this:

```
,monkey,pig
```

Any ideas?

Ok guys the code istself looks like this

```
a = raw_input(">>")
uAlpha = a.split(",")
```

Now I know how to remove the /r but how to prevent it from getting there in the first place ?

Comment: Simple: just remove the carriage return.

Comment: The problem is that this new array is created when splitting output and python adds the /r by itself to the last string in array. Any way to prevent this from happening automatically ?

Comment: Python does no such thing, it doesn't just add `\r` characters without cause. Can you show us how you got the input in the first place?

Comment: a = raw_input(">>")
uAlpha = a.split(",")
When doing this last string in uAlpha ends with /r.

Comment: @ign699 Python does not add the `\r`; your command shell (Windows, presumably) is passing a `\r\n`-terminated string to Python's standard input.

Comment: @ign699: and how are you passing in the data to Python? Is this coming from some other subsystem?

Comment: I run the code through notepad++ using python -u -i $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).

Answer (score 8):

`\r` is a carriage return character, so it is doing exactly what it should. The string is actually `dog\r,monkey,pig`, but when you print it, it looks like `,monkey,pig` due to what `\r` does (moves the cursor to the beginning of the line). Try this to strip the carriage return (and any other white space) from the strings:

```
>>> array=['dog\r', 'monkey', 'pig']
>>> ",".join(s.strip() for s in array)
dog,monkey,pig
```

Alternatively, if you posted your code, we might be able to help you to get the "\r" from being on there in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You are including a carriage return in your string. You are instructing the terminal to move the cursor back to the start of the line and continue printing from there.

You built the string:

```
'dog\r,monkey,pig'
```

and are printing that, which results in first `dog` being printed, then the cursor moving back to the start of the line (returning the 'printing carriage'), then the rest being printed *overwriting the `dog` text*.

Either remove the carriage return from your input, or from your joined string. You could use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.repace) or [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to remove all carriage return characters, or use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) (and variants) to remove them from the start and end of a string when you still have the list.

For example, if your input is coming from `raw_input()`, you could simply use [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove carriage returns from the end:

```
a = raw_input(">>").rstrip('\r')
uAlpha = a.split(",")
```

Answer (score 2):

The return character was causing it to skip the first part, you can see the difference by using `repr`

```
>>> print ",".join(array)
,monkey,pig
>>> print repr(",".join(array))
'dog\r,monkey,pig'
```

Use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove the return character

```
>>> array=['dog\r', 'monkey', 'pig']
>>> ",".join(map(str.strip,array))
```

The output is

```
'dog,monkey,pig'
```

Note that it is slightly better to use `map` rather than a comprehension to strip characters. The `timeit` results

```
$ python -m timeit "','.join(s.strip() for s in ['dog\r', 'monkey', 'pig'])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "','.join(map(str.strip,['dog\r', 'monkey', 'pig']))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.647 usec per loop
```

The use of `map` vs comprehensions is discussed here.

The most popular (and accepted answer) conclusion is quoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map):

> map may be ***microscopically*** faster in some cases (when you're NOT making a lambda for the purpose, but using the same function in map and a listcomp).